# ScrollView - Send Touches to View below

Tags: ios, scrollview, gestures, touches

My setup - and I cannot change it - is right now:

Root View
- UIView
-- ScrollView2
- ScrollView1  (this is top in view hierarchy)

The first scrollview is used to apply some transitions on the below UIView. The second scrollviews contentoffset (captures in scrollViewDidScroll:) is used to apply other animations.

**Question:** How can I transfer/delegate all touches from ScrollView1 to ScrollView2? Please note that the ScrollView1 is on top of everything and the others views are **below** of it - not subviews!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the pan gesture recogniser from a scroll view to any other view you want and this will effectively delegate the touches from the targeted view to the scroll view. You can also add the pinch gesture recogniser if you want to control zoom.